# ¿como puedo hacer que mi proyecto que tengo en localhost sea visible en las computadoras de mi red local?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema y espero me puedan apoyar, tengo un proyecto desarollado con php lo tengo en una carpeta dentro de `htdocs` de xampp quiero accesar a dicho proyecto desde otra computadora dentro de la misma red local, hice lo siguiente para poder accesar:

- Puse IP estática
- Habilite una regla de entrada para el puerto 80 en el firewall
- Configure apache httpd-xampp.conf
- Desactive mi antivirus

Mi proyecto tiene una pagina de bienvenida y después el login esas dos paginas son las únicas que logre ver , después de poner usuario y contraseña no pasa del login se redirige a una pagina donde hago la validación del usuario pero me sale error como cuando no hay Internet esto en el navegador.
¿Quizás sea un error en mi código que impida pasar del login pero no se alguna idea ??

Esta es la pagina que aparece en la url pero me aparece error como cuando no hay Internet aquí hago mis validaciones de usuario administrador / usuario:

**validar.php**

```php
    <?php session_start();

    require 'admin/config.php';
    require 'functions.php';

    // comprobar session
    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
     {
      // validar los datos por privilegio
      $conexion = conexion($bd_config);
      $usuario = iniciarSession('usuarios', $conexion);

      if ($usuario['tipo'] == 'administrador')
      {
        header('Location: '.RUTA.'admin.php');
      }
       elseif ($usuario['tipo'] == 'usuario')
      {
        header('Location: '.RUTA.'usuario.php');
      } 
      else
      {
        header('Location: '.RUTA.'login.php');
      }
    } 
    else 
    {
      header('Location: '.RUTA.'login.php');
    }

     ?>
```

Este es mi codigo al cual hace referencia en require:

**functions.php**

```php
    <?php

    function conexion($bd_config){
      try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['db_name'],$bd_config['user'],$bd_config['pass']);
        return $conexion;
      } 
      catch (PDOException $e) 
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function limpiarDatos($datos)
    {
      $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
      $datos = trim($datos);
      $datos = filter_var($datos, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      return $datos;
    }

    function iniciarSession($table, $conexion)
    {
      $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE usuario = :usuario");
      $statement->execute([
        ':usuario' => $_SESSION['usuario']
      ]);
      return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    ?>
```

Aquí esta el otro archivo del require:

**config.php**

```php
    <?php
    define('RUTA', 'http://localhost/control_flotilla/');

    //variables para la conexion a base de datos
    $bd_config=[
    'db_name'=>'controldeflotilla',
    'user'=>'root',
    'pass'=>''
    ];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que andes bien.  ¿Has tratado de reemplazar?

```
define('RUTA', 'http://localhost/control_flotilla/');
```

por algunas de las siguientes opciones:

**RED LAN**

```
define('RUTA', 'http://TU-IP-LAN/control_flotilla/');
```

**INTERNET**

```
define('RUTA', 'http://TU-IP-PUBLICA/control_flotilla/');
```

Intenta con eso, cualquier duda o consulta la puedes comentar.

**Explicación del error**

Básicamente esto pasa, porque, la redirección que hace **PHP**, es directamente a `localhost`, es decir, al **servidor local** del **usuario** que visita el sitio. Por lo que como el **usuario** en cuestión no tiene un servidor en ordenador, el navegador intentará acceder a una página que no encuentra.

Como te comentan, para el acceso desde una red `LAN` debes poner tu IP dentro de la red. Si el acceso es de una red `INTERNET` debes poner tu IP pública, y si tienes router, **redirigir el puerto** `80` (de la conexión entrante) a tu `IP local` (la IP que tienes dentro de la red LAN).

**Redirecciones relativas**

También puedes realizar una **redirección relativa** dentro de PHP de la siguiente forma:

```
define('RUTA', '/control_flotilla/');
```

En el siguiente enlace se explican con detalle las redirecciones dentro de **PHP**:
[Redireccionar a otra página web con PHP](http://creatosfera.com/site/redireccionar-otra-pagina-web-php/)

**Servidor de pruebas de PHP**

Adicionalmente, en vez de usar XAMP, puedes usar el servidor de pruebas que trae integrado **PHP**, sin embargo, el servidor no se debe usar para entornos de producción, solo para desarrollo y pruebas.

[PHP: Servidor web interno - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: muchas gracias sabia que era algo de mi código y por lo visto así fue era algo tan sencillo , muchas gracias por la explicación si me sirvió de mucho ya comprendí mejor las re direcciones.